# Программа выдает ощибку при установке через .apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Доброго времени суток. Сделал программу, всегда тестировал ее через отладку на реальном устройстве. Когда пришло время создать Apk файл, начались проблемы. 
Программа запускает первый экран где не чего не загружается с серверов и тд. самый простой Activity, но как только я хочу начать использовать программу, и перехожу на более сложную по строению страницу, он выдает ошибку и пишет в логах

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class (тут класс в котором ошибка ).

я проверил класс, он исправно работает при запуске через (провод) а не через установку приложения

подскажите в каком направлении капать...   и как лечить

Добавил.1

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid, PID: 2593
                                                                            com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid.BeatchJava.Beatch
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid.BeatchJava.Beatch_List_ViewActivity$1.onChildAdded(Beatch_List_ViewActivity.java:80)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

класс Beatch

```
public class Beatch {
    String name;
    static String key;
  public Beatch() {
    }public Beatch(String name, String key) {
    this.name = name;
    this.key = key;
}
}`
```

Класс в котором происходит получение данных

```
 reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Beatch.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            LoadongBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

место ошибки строка `result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Beatch.class));`

Comment: подробнее можно логи ошибки, и того класса, в котором вы использовали библиотеку Firebase Database

Comment: @Антон обновил вопрос

Comment: У вас обработчики кнопок как установлены? Если через создание доп.методов, то возможно ошибка в этом

Comment: @SlandShow  public void myBottonClickOpenBeatch(View view){
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Beatch_List_ViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }

Comment: @V Teme попробуйте так: button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });

Comment: @SlandShow к сожалению это не помогло, проблема появляется не на стадии открытия а на стадии получения данных(

Comment: а Firebase то где задействован? в каком классе? если он выводит ошибку, то дело именно в его использовании. Укажите место, где вы его используете? Просто если просто подключить firebasedatabase , то ошибок быть не должно

Comment: @Антон обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить геттеры и сеттеры, так например:

```
public class Beatch {
    String name;
    String key;
    public Beatch() {
    }
    public Beatch(String name, String key) {
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня после такой манипуляции выдает ошибку. 
Что он находит 2 гетера для переменных , и я не как ни могу понять где он. как это можно узнать?